# C# TcpClient streamreader with eventhandler not all messages are processed

Tags: c#, xml, events, stream, tcpclient

I'm reading continuously from a TcpClient streamreader.
The data coming from the stream is raw XML. There is no message framing. So there is now reliable method to know when the message is finished. Though I only have 3 XML messages coming from the server. But when they are coming is unknown. And I can't configure/program the server.
This is my code so far.

```
        public void Start()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_tcpClient.GetStream());
        char[] chars = new char[Int16.MaxValue];
        while (!_requestStop)
        {
            try
            {
                while ((reader.Read(chars, 0, chars.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    string s = new string(chars);
                    s = removeEmptyChars(s);
                    if (s.IndexOf("<foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 &&
                        s.IndexOf("</foo>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                        OnAlarmResponseComplete(new CustomEventArgs(s));
                    }
                    if (s.IndexOf("<bar", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 &&
                        s.IndexOf("</bar>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                        OnAckComplete(new CustomEventArgs(s));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                //break;
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping TcpReader thread!");
    }
```

Then in my main thread I'm processing the events. I'm adding them to a list.
Where I process the list.
When I'm debugging my application, I will be receiving 10 foo and 10 bar messages. And in my lists I have only 1 foo and 1 bar message stored.

Are the eventhandlers to slow to process this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You re invoking the event handlers synchronously therefore it does not matter whether they are executing fast or slow. I think the problem might be expecting the start and end tags in the same receive. If for instance, you receive <foo>................... but not </foo> in the same packet, your code will not call the event handlers.

Comment: I could narrow down the problem even more. When I receive <foo ..... </foo> message It can contain <foo ... </foo> <bar ... </bar> <foo ... </foo>.

Comment: :) Very nice. Can you mark my coment useful then? :) Do you need help overcoming that issue?

Comment: Yes I would like some help with that. And I would gladly like to mark your comment as useful. But I can't :(

Comment: I see. Reputation issues :) Anyways, I will enter an answer now. You can check that to see if it works for you.

Comment: Look at your variable 's'.  Only the last 's' is being saved.  You need to append the 's' variable something like this : s += s;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you should use to cover all kinds of input issues (foo or bar received partially, foo and bar received together, etc..)

I can't say I approve using string parsing to handle XML content, but anyways.

```
private static string ProcessAndTrimFooBar(string s, out bool foundAny)
{
    foundAny = false;

    int fooStart = s.IndexOf("<foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int fooEnd = s.IndexOf("</foo>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int barStart = s.IndexOf("<bar", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int barEnd = s.IndexOf("</bar>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    bool fooExists = fooStart >= 0 && fooEnd >= 0;
    bool barExists = barStart >= 0 && barEnd >= 0;

    if ((fooExists && !barExists) || (fooExists && barExists && fooStart < barStart))
    {
        string fooNodeContent = s.Substring(fooStart, fooEnd - fooStart + 6);
        s = s.Substring(fooEnd + 6);
        Console.WriteLine("Received <foo>: {0}", fooNodeContent);
        OnAlarmResponseComplete(new CustomEventArgs(fooNodeContent));
        foundAny = true;
    }

    if ((barExists && !fooExists) || (barExists && fooExists && barStart < fooStart))
    {
        string barNodeContent = s.Substring(barStart, barEnd - barStart + 6);
        s = s.Substring(barEnd + 6);
        Console.WriteLine("Received <bar>: {0}", barNodeContent);
        OnAckComplete(new CustomEventArgs(barNodeContent));
        foundAny = true;
    }

    return s;
}

public static void Start()
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_tcpClient.GetStream());
    char[] chars = new char[Int16.MaxValue];
    while (!_requestStop)
    {
        try
        {
            int currentOffset = 0;
            while ((reader.Read(chars, currentOffset, chars.Length - currentOffset)) != 0)
            {
                string s = new string(chars).TrimEnd('\0');

                bool foundAny;

                do
                {
                    s = ProcessAndTrimFooBar(s, out foundAny);
                } while (foundAny);

                chars = s.PadRight(Int16.MaxValue, '\0').ToCharArray();
                currentOffset = s.Length;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            //break;
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Stopping TcpReader thread!");
}
```

Comment: This code is not working :(. If you have any other way of not string processing xml I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: Interesting, because it works for me! :) Can you give the details of "not working"

Comment: Well it is working. But the event handlers are doing weird things. I made a list and added barNodeContent and fooBarNodeContent. And all 20 items are perfectly in the [list](http://imgur.com/OKj12Nl) . But when I'm passing them to the eventhandler I get rubbish in my [end list](http://imgur.com/0OFIl5w).

Comment: I cannot access the imgur web site (It is just another censored web site by a Turkish court.) What is now sent to the event handlers are the exact node outer xml for foo and bar nodes, like <foo>....</foo> or <bar>....</bar>. I will try to access imgur through a proxy now.

Comment: I've found the problem. It is, the code is not sending the <foo> and <bar> content to the event handlers, but is sending the remaining string.. I am fixing the code to send to the event handlers barNodeContent and fooBarNodeContent

Comment: Yes it was. So dumb of me that I didn't notice that. Thank you for the effort. If you have another way of processing xml without strings. I would be happy to hear more about it. Just pointing in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome. You can check [XmlTextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow fast, forward only access to an xml stream.

Comment: If I wanted to add a third mesage (not just bar, foo, aaa for example) that I want to process similar to these could you show me what to add. Because I tried all morning and didn't succeed, I don't understand the if condition 100%.

Comment: We need to alter the design then. We cannot just copy blocks of code whenever we need to adda new tag.